# Limiting File Access to One User at a Time on Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to set up a SharePoint folder where all of the files in it can be accessed by only one user at a time. While the file is open on one users account I want it so that no other user can view the file at all until it has been closed by the initial user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible using OOTB SharePoint.

You could try writing an app to ensure your needs. Something along the lines of:

- Use item-level permissions
- disable all access
- create a ui to request access for one user

  - on request grant, grant access to the one user
  - ensure the user releases access to the document somehow.

However, I would recommend **aginst** developing such a solution.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: If this answered the question, pleas mark the answer.